# Angular testing Service with params return an mocked observable

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I'm still new to all different kinds of unit-testing and I'm once more stuck on a test for a service.

This is the function in my service I want to test:

```
For your information:
this.setParams returns an object like {name: 'Test', id: 3}


  getDataCount(dataparams: Filter): Observable<number> {
    const url = 'http://blablabla.com';
    const params = this.setParams(dataparams);
    return new Observable<number>(observer => {
      this.httpc.get<number>(url, { params }).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
        }
      );
    }
    );
  }
```

The setup for my test is:

```
describe('MyDataService', () => {
  let service: DataService;
  let mockParams: Filter;
  let mockCount: number;

  mockParams = { name: 'Test', id: 3 };
  mockCount = 358;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
        ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
  });
```

My test looks like this:

```
  it('should return mockCount', async () => {
    const test = await service.getOperatingDataCount(mockParams).toPromise();
    expect(test).toBe(mockCount);
  });
```

but it's returning 'Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)'. I read other threads, too, but I'm still not able to figure out how to write an appropiate test for this. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `await` the promise after calling `req.flush()`. It will respond with mock data, causing the `this.httpc.get()` Observable to resolve.

Only when your observable emits a value, your promise can be resolved or rejected.
Therefore, before you call `req.flush()`, the promise cannot be resolved and rejected, which leads to timeout error.

Here is a working example using `"@angular/core": "~11.0.3"`

`data.service.ts`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export type Filter = any;

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private httpc: HttpClient) {}
  setParams(dataparams: Filter) {
    return dataparams;
  }
  getDataCount(dataparams: Filter): Observable<number> {
    const url = 'http://blablabla.com';
    const params = this.setParams(dataparams);
    return new Observable<number>((observer) => {
      this.httpc
        .get<number>(url, { params })
        .subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
        });
    });
  }
}
```

`data.service.spec.ts`:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataService, Filter } from './data.service';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

fdescribe('MyDataService', () => {
  let dataService: DataService;
  let mockParams: Filter;
  let mockCount: number;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [DataService],
    });
    dataService = TestBed.inject(DataService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should get data', async () => {
    mockParams = { name: 'Test', id: 3 };
    mockCount = 358;

    const promise = dataService.getDataCount(mockParams).toPromise();
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
      'http://blablabla.com?name=Test&id=3'
    );
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(mockCount);
    const actual = await promise;
    expect(actual).toBe(358);
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

[image]